# Wpf - bestway to register a change on property

Tags: wpf

Whatsup, I'm new to **wpf** technology and im having trouble to find out how to popup a message on screen when there is a change on the User property. (Except that, the code works perfect).

*My goal is to register an exsisting event that takes care of it and NOT to do it in the MyData class by rewriting the 'Set'.
**xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel x:Name="MyGrid1">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <local:MyData x:Key="mySource1"
                      User="Arik2" />
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <TextBox x:Name="target1"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="2"
              Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource mySource1}, Path=User,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="target2"
              Grid.Row="2"
              Grid.Column="2"
              Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource mySource1}, Path=User,Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Thats my app code:**

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
    public class MyData
    {
        public string User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the textboxes you have you can always open a message window in a textchanged event handler.

For example

```
<TextBox TextChanged="txt_TextChanged" >

Private Sub txt_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("Value changed")
    End Sub
```

Note this is probably what you are looking for but is triggering off the text in the box changing not the property itself. If you use anything like validation and input invalid data this event will fire but the text will not change.

I think you can use the sourcechanged event to get exactly what you want.

Comment: thats perfect but anyway to use the binding object for doing it? im trying to learn all the ways.

Comment: What is sourcechanged event? where can i register ?

Comment: Try the sourceupdated event as I mentioned. You have to be careful doing this kind of thing on the binding as you may not want a message box to open when the value is changed via code.

Comment: You can register it in the text box xaml exactly as the textchanged one is registered.

Comment: Normally, the `MyData` class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.  In the setters of your properties, you raise the `PropertyChanged` event, passing a string containing the name of the property that was just changed.  You then set the Mode of your bindings to `TwoWay`.  The UI would update automatically when the setter is called, and the property's value would change if the user edited the value of the property.  But to open a dialog when the value changes, you need to use the `TextChanged` event on the UI control. There is no other way to bring up a dialog in the UI.

Comment: @kenjara The sourceupdated give me an update befor the changing. so int he event there is only the old User and not the new changed one.

Comment: If it is only firing on the initial binding it is likely your data class is not implementing INotifiyPropertyChanged as mentioned by Tony. It will notify the UI that the data has changed. You can read more about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged